# How can I get this npm script working consistently?

Tags: typescript, npm

I have these 2 very simple scripts in my npm package:

```json
"prebuild": "rimraf dist types",
"build": "tsc",
```

I have both `rimraf@^5.0.5` and `typescript@^5.3.2` installed as development dependencies. Whenever I execute `npm run build` I get inconsistent behavior:

- The first time I execute it (before any build files are created) it does nothing. No errors are thrown either.
- If I then simply execute `tsc` in the same working directory, it will generate build files as it should.
- If I then run `npm run build`, it will work flawlessly, deleting the existing `dist` and `types` directories and then generating new build files.
- If I then run `npm run build` again, it will delete the `dist` and `types` directories, but won't generate any new build files. No errors are thrown.

I would expect `npm run build` to simply replace any existing `dist` and `types` directories withnew/updated build files every time I execute it.

Comment: Please give a [mre], I've [used similar patterns](https://github.com/textbook/express-msgpack/blob/c7642ebcf34ee3a994125a48e5c2aef41a63dbd5/package.json#L16-L17) without issue.

Comment: @jonrsharpe Well, looks like I could trace it down to a tsconfig extension, after removing it the script works flawlessly everytime. I guess that proves one of the purposes of creating a minimal reproducible example! Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

An extension to the project's tsconfig (`@sapphire/tsconfig`) was causing the issue.

It enabled the `tsBuildInfoFile` option which generates a `tsconfig.tsbuildinfo` upon transpilation. I added this file to be removed by `rimraf` in the `prebuild` script and it now works as expected.

Comment: it will be better if you can name the extension , so that other can relate it .